# Landau's proof of MMT (Maximum Modulus Theorem)

Tags: complex-analysis

This is an exercise of Newman's book ans says this is a proof, due to Landau, of the maximum modulus theorem, but I'm not getting how to prove it.

Suppose $f$ is an analytic inside and on a circle $C$ with $|f(z)|\leq M$ on $C$ and suppose $z_0$ is a point inside $C$.Use Cauchy’sintegral formula to show that $|f(z_0)|^n \leq KM^n$ where $K$ is independent of $n$.

Answer (score 1):

A hint: Apply the Cauchy formula to $f^n$.

Comment: okay got it now, thanks

Comment: @dragoboy : I may need some more help here. How should I proceed?