# How does this prove the Maximum modulus theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

In short how does this:

[Landau's Proof of the Maximum Modulus Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1545476/landaus-proof-of-the-maximum-modulus-theorem)

prove the maximum modulus theorem?

It is not clear to me that this proof shows that the maximum of an analytic function must occur on the boundary of domain. Infact it seems to me that all we have done is rearrived at the assumption $f(z) \leq M$, just with $z= z_0$.

Can anyone clarify. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need that $C$ is open an $\partial C$ has finite length $L$, we assume $f$ is analytic on an open containing $C\cup \partial C$, obtaining for $z_0\in C$ $$2i\pi f(z_0)^n = \int_{\partial C}\frac{f(z)^n}{z-z_0}dz, \qquad 2\pi |f(z_0)|^n \le \frac{L}{dist(z_0,\partial C)} M^n$$

where $M^n = \sup_{z\in \partial C} |f(z)^n|$

If $|f(z_0)|>M$ this wouldn't be satisfied for $n$ large enough