# why $2i\pi f(z_0)^n = \int_{\partial C}\frac{f(z)^n}{z-z_0}dz ?$

Tags: complex-analysis

This user is not active for many days , so i posted my doubt

I have  some  doubt in  this  answer [doubt](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3487921/557708)

My doubt is given below  marked in red circle

[image]

My attempt :   i know that cauchy integral formula is  given by $$f(z_0)^n= \frac{n!}{2\pi i} \int_C \frac{f(z)}{ (z-z_0)^{n+1}}$$

But its  given different form in the given answer

So im not getting  why  $2i\pi f(z_0)^n = \int_{\partial C}\frac{f(z)^n}{z-z_0}dz ?$

Comment: You confused the $n^{\text{th}}$ power with the $n^{\text{th}}$ derivative. The integral you wrote is for the derivative, the integral in the image is for the power.

Comment: okk @DanielFischer  but  if $ n^{th}$power then it should be like   $(\int_{\partial C}\frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}dz)^n$...

Comment: Consider the function $g(z) = f(z)^n$ and the usual integral formula for $g$.

Comment: got its..  thanks u @DanielFischer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cauchy's integral formula is

$$f^{(n)}(z_0)= \frac{n!}{2\pi i} \oint_C \frac{f(z)}{ (z-z_0)^{n+1}}\, dz$$

In particular:

$$g(z_0)= \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_C \frac{g(z)}{ z-z_0}\, dz$$

Let $g(z_0) = [f(z_0)]^n.$